# Can you write a dust.js condition based upon a scalar value?

Tags: dust.js

Brand new to Dust and trying to do something that I had hoped would be fairly simple.  Very basically, I have a Backbone model with an attribute of page that has the value 'home'.  I need to display a certain block of html based upon that value.  If 'home', display this block of code, that sort of thing.  I don't even know if Dust will work like that, but the requirements for the project require that the page presentation be handled via Dust, so I'm starting with what I have.  All the examples I'm seeing appear to focus on arrays when it comes to conditionals in the templates.  Anyone know of a total noob sort of tutorial for Dust?  Any insights greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the `@eq` helper. Dust helpers are separate from the core of Dust, and can be found here: https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs-helpers

An example of how the Dust would look using `@eq`:

```
{@eq key=page value="home"}
    {! Display "home" page content here !}
{:else}
    {! Otherwise, display other content !}
{/eq}
```

If you have multiple pages, you will probably want to use the `@select` helper in conjunction with the `@eq` helper:

```
{@select key=page}
    {@eq value="home"}
        {! home page !}
    {/eq}
    {@eq value="about"}
        {! about page !}
    {/eq}
    {@eq value="contact"}
        {! contact page !}
    {/eq}
{/select}
```